# Postfix - Can Send / Receive Localy - Send External - Not receive from external

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, fail2ban, postgrey

I just finish configuring my own mail server using this guide:
[LinuxBabe Guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu)

At the start all was working but now I can not receive mail from external.
Here is my configuration file:
https://hatebin.com/npslpqyqpr

Comment: What error are you experiencing?  What do your logs show?  Does your firewall permit incoming connections?  Have you set the MX records for the domain (how long ago)?  Does your provider block port 25?

Comment: Everything is good for Firewall, I got 25 allow, Ufw correctly set up, No error on log file. MX record are set up and i got a 10/10 score on mail tester. Also MX Toolbox everything is ok.

Comment: What are the symptoms of your error?  You are not giving much data to diagnose the problem.  What happens if you `telnet <your server ip> 25` from another machine?

Comment: Connection to shiori.dev:25 - ok
220 shiori.dev

As I said, all the set up is ok. I do not see any error in log file, is there a way to see more warning / error ?

Answer (score 0):

Your name appears to have a dozen or more IPv6 addresses set in the DNS, but as far as I can tell none of them actually respond on any port. Mail providers which also use IPv6 (such as Google or Microsoft and many others) will try those addresses and get a timeout, then queue the mail to try again later.

Your server does answer SMTP on IPv4, but it can take hours or even days before the mail sender gets around to trying the IPv4 address.

You should either fix your IPv6 connectivity or remove the AAAA records from your DNS.

Comment: Ok got it. Will try out to fix those IPV6 issue